# Does Google support the amr claim OpenID Connect MODRNA

Tags: google-oauth, google-openid, google-signin

Does Google support [OpenID Connect MODRNA Authentication Profile 1.0](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-modrna-authentication-1_0.html).

Or provide any method that a OpenID Connect Client can determine if MFA was used as part of the Authentication Process?

Comment: Appears neither Google or Apple support the amr claim or any other fashion to determine how the "user" was authenticated.
This make it quite hard for "clients" to determine the Level of Assurance for Authentication. Microsoft does support the amr claim.